# The same material looks different

Tags: texturing, materials

Please I need your help, I have not been able to deal with it for several days.

Does anyone know why the same material added to another object looks different? I mean rough surface appearance – the size of the bumps and the amount of reflected light etc.

Nodes and material properties are exactly the same (attaching the screenshots).[image]

[image]

---

Hi thanks guys for your reply! after doing Ctrl-A> Scale something like this happens (screenshot). The second object gets very small.[image]

Comment: Do both objects have the Scale applied? (Ctrl-A > Scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in your **Texture Coordinates Node**. You use the **Object** output as the vector reference - this is used for scaling (placing, rotating).

But as you have two different objects the calculation of the scaling is different for both seperate objects. Though applying *Scale* to both objects as explained by the others (`Ctrl + A -> Scale` or even better `Ctrl + A -> Rotation & Scale`) should have been enough (and is important anyways), there is an additional handy solution:

You can add an *Empty* to the scene and then use that *Empty* in the input field for **Object** in your **Texture Coordinate Node** and use the Object output. Then the reference for scaling of the textures will be that same object (*Empty*) no matter which object the material is applied to. You can then even scale the *Empty* to change the scale of the material on all objects it is applied to.

To add the *Empty*: Like you would add any Mesh: `Shift + A -> Empty -> Cube` (or any other).

[image: 3 objects 1 shader with Empty for Texture Coordinates]

Comment: Adding Empty completely solved the problem, thanks a lot for your help!!! I was looking for a solution for 2 days. Yes, I'm a noob :)

Comment: Glad it helped! Just be aware: If you use procedural textures and want to animate, because then the textures will move too :-) For animations you might wanna use baked UV textures (another topic, but just so you're aware).

Comment: Yes, objects with these textures will be animated, so good to know :) I will try to deal with it, if I fail, I will come back here :) Thanks again!

Comment: If the objects only are simply transformed (scale, move, rotate) in animation, the Empty solution still can work (with parenting). For more complex animations, shape keys, rigs: It will be not suitable - but you can then still have your procedural textures but would use the UV output instead (UV unwrap your objects). Have fun exploring.

Comment: Thank you so much! In this case it will be only simple transformations, but good to know for the future. I'm just learning how to use Bledner, but I'm already in love! :)

Answer (score 1):

The objects probably don't have the same scale applied to them. If you select both the objects, then click on ctrl+a and then click on "scale", it will apply the scale of both the objects, making them the same.