# Scaling texture doesn't work properly

Tags: texturing, uv, transforms

I have been trying to make an object with a texture. In render it looks good but when I export it in FBX for Coohom something goes wrong.

[image]

So the upper part is the correct scale, the one underneath isn't.

I have tried different unwrappings (UV, Normal unwrap,..) Also tried to unwrap them together.

I also used an empty to the texture coordinate to make sure that the scale would be right everywhere (Like here [The same material looks different](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275305/the-same-material-looks-different) )  , so I really don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Also did ctrl + a - all transformations.

my file: [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I will add it right now, thank you!

Comment: Not sure exactly what's causing the problem, and it's hard to tell because you didn't pack your textures, but disconnecting the Object Texture coordinate and then reconnecting it seems to have _some_ effect. Try it out.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know tomorrow if this worked. I will look into packing textures to. I copy pasted this out of my whole project for clearance

Comment: Hello, I have updated my file :)

Comment: All seems fine for me (Blender 4.0) with this new file...

Comment: Even when you export it to fbx? Now i'm even more confused on what I am doing wrong aaa

Comment: If fbx all image texture nodes will be converted to "flat" (instead of "box")... so yes, this is the issue.

Comment: Okay thank you I will check out how to do the uv map thing, I have never had this problem before this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in comments that the issue occurs after fbx export/import,

Yes this is the cause of the issue:

Original materials have image texture nodes set to "box".

[image]

But after fbx export this is lost and is now "flat".

[image]

As there is no option to preserve that ("box" projection), you should use a UV map instead.

---

Complement, following comments.

Fbx imported material will use the UV map.

But UV map should be scaled appropriately, between meshes, so that the ratio over the textures are equivalent from a given mesh to the other ones:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I will research and try this out :)

Comment: Hello do you maybe have a link with more information about this? I just checked a video and it says I have an uv map, so I'm not sure what to do..

Comment: You effectively already have one but is surface ratio (between meshes) correct?

Comment: Okay thanks got it, so i have to scale them the same size? I thought adding the empty for the texture coordination made sure its the same size everywhere. So for every object I have to do it this way?

Comment: Okay this way I can indeed change the scale, thank you very much! Can I ask how you made the preview so light? I Can't really see what i'm doing unless i export in fbx https://prnt.sc/78NEvFCFHn27

Comment: Yes adjust manually the scale of the uv maps.

Comment: The preview was not using the scene world (but preview world).

Comment: Keep in mind that as objects are separated, you may have seams between the mesh parts.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will join it in 1 again now